# About Continuity of function defined on an interval $(0,∞)$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

I just Practicing analysis after long time. I need help in following question.

**Question** given that $A=(0,∞)$ and let $k:A→\mathbb{R}$ defined as follows, for $x\in A\cap\mathbb{Q}^c$ we define $k(x)=0$ and for $x\in A\cap\mathbb{Q}$ where $x$ is of the form $x=\frac{m}{n}$ with $m,n$ are natural numbers having no common factors except $1$, we define $k(x)=n$ then prove that, $k$ is unbounded on every open interval in $A$ and conclude that $k$ is not continuous at any point of $A$.

**My attempt**: Somehow i manage to prove $k$ is not Continuous at rational points of $A$ as follows:

Let $a$ be rational point of $A=(0,∞)$ and let $(y_n)$ be sequence of irrationals in $A$ that converges to $a$ (such a sequence does exists by density theorem) then we have $k(y_n)= 0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and hence $lim(k(y_n))=0$ whereas, $k(a)>0$ and hence by sequential criterion of continuity we have $k$ is not continuous at $a$. Hence it follows that, $k$ is not continuous on any rational points of $A$.

But, how to prove discontinuity of $k$ at irrational points of $A$? and how to show $k$ is unbounded on every open interval in $A$? Further, question asked conclude discontinuity from first part (unbounded part). Please help me.

Comment: I'm confused by your query.  If I understand correctly, the range of $k(x)$ is a subset of $\mathbb{Z}.$  Based on this, since both $Q$ and $Q^c$ are both dense in $\mathbb{R}$, isn't it immediately impossible for $k$ to be continuous anywhere?

Comment: @user2661923 where did i said $k$ is continuous?

Comment: +1 good point.  What I reacted to was "...I manage to prove k is not Continuous at ..." and "... But, how to prove discontinuity of k at irrational points of A?...".  If I am interpreting your query correctly, you took time to prove discontinuity on $Q$ and then focused on discontinuity on $Q^c$.  For me, the deciding factor is that range of $k(x) \subseteq \mathbb{Z}.$  This means that if $k(x_1) = n$, the only way that $k$ could be continuous at $x_1$ is if there was a neighborhood  around $x_1$ such that $k$ was constant in this neighborhood.  This is immediately seen to be impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a<b$. Pick a rational number $\frac p q$ with $(p,q)=1$ in this interval. Let $N$ be a prime number. It is easy to check that $(pN+q,qN)=1$ if $N$ is large enough. Note that $\frac p  q+\frac  1N$ is also in $(a,b)$ if $N$ is large enough. Also $k(\frac p  q+\frac  1N) =qN$. This proves that $k$ is unbounded on $(a,b)$.

Suppose $k$ is continuous at some point $x$. Then $|k(y)-k(x)| <1$ for all $y$ in some interval $(x-r,x+r)$ around $x$. But this implies that $k$ is bounded  by $1+|k(x)|$  in this interval. This contradicts what we proved above so $k$ cannot be continuous at any point.

Comment: Sir, $k(\frac p  q+\frac  1N) =qN$, This proves that $k$ is unbounded on $(a,b)$? How? Can you please elaborate this line.

Comment: In my argument I can choose $N$ as large as I want. I just want it to be a large prime number.  @AkashPatalwanshi

Comment: Thank you so much sir.